# Playwright test results not publishing in Azure pipelines

Tags: azure-pipelines, playwright

We have number of playwright tests that execute as part of our deployment pipeline. The yml file that kicks off the tests also has the following tasks:

```
  - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
    displayName: "Playwright-Publish Traces"
    condition: or(failed(), canceled())
    inputs:
      PathToPublish: "${{ params.testDir }}/test-results"
      ArtifactName: "Playwright Test Traces"
      publishLocation: "Container"

  - task: PublishTestResults@2
    displayName: "Playwright-Publish Results"
    inputs:
      testResultsFormat: 'JUnit'
      testResultsFiles: '*.xml'
      searchFolder: "${{ params.testDir }}/test-results"
      testRunTitle: "Playwright Tests ${{ params.shardIndex }}/${{ params.totalShards }}"  
    condition: always()
```

After the test run completes, I can see that the test traces are published in the artifacts section of Azure, but not the test result report (screenshots below).  Why is that?

[image]
[image]

If I run the playwright tests locally, then I can see a `results.xml` published in the `test-results` directory as expected.

Looking at the logs of the `Playwright-Publish Results` step in the pipeline looks as though everything went well:
[image]

I did notice that if I follow the url linked in the pipeline logs, I get a 404 error though, so perhaps they're not publishing to the right place?  Looking at the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/publish-test-results-v2?view=azure-pipelines&tabs=trx%2Ctrxattachments%2Cyaml) for this task, I can't see an option to specify a `publishLocation` like you can for the `PublishBuildArtifacts` task though.

****Edit**** Just to clarify, I can see the test results presented in Azure under the tests tab, but I want to retrieve a copy of the raw results.xml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> After the test run completes, I can see that the test traces are published in the artifacts section of Azure, but not the test result report (screenshots below). Why is that?

As per the artifact name `Playwright Test Traces`, it comes from your `PublishBuildArtifacts@1` task in your yaml. The task will create the artifact not publish the test result, the task works as expected.

[image]

For last screenshot of task `PublishTestResults@2`, it will publish the test as you wanted, but it has the message: `No build level attachments to publish`.

[image]

But on your summmary page, it actually has tests rate:

[image]

1. Please double confirm on `Tests` tab, to check if there's any test result:

[image]

2. You have published the folder content in the artifact `Playwright Test Traces`, it's recommended to check its content to double confirm test result xml is correctly generated or contained. Check if there are `multiple` xml result files. If you have, you can specify one xml to publish in `PublishTestResults@2` task, or use one more `PublishTestResults@2` task to publish the other xml result.

Edit:

I created the Playwright test sample project via command  `npm init playwright@latest`. As per the [doc](https://playwright.dev/docs/ci#uploading-playwright-report-folder-with-azure-pipelines)， added the `output` format in `playwright.config.ts`.

[image]

I have yaml pipeline below:

```
name: Playwright Tests
variables:
  CI: true
trigger:
  - main
jobs:
  - job: test
    timeoutInMinutes: 60
    pool:
      vmImage: "ubuntu-latest"
    steps:
      - task: NodeTool@0
        inputs:
          versionSpec: "16.x"
        displayName: "Install Node.js"
      - script: |
         npm ci
         npm install -g junit-viewer
        displayName: "Install dependencies"
      - script: npx playwright install --with-deps
        displayName: "Install Playwright Browsers"
      - script: npx playwright test
        displayName: "Run Playwright tests"

      # - script: npx junit-viewer --results=$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/test-results/test-results.xml --output=$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/playwright-report/index.html
      #   displayName: "Generate result.xml"

      - powershell: Get-ChildItem -Path . -File -Recurse
      - publish: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/test-results
        artifact: playwright-report
        condition: always()

      - task: PublishTestResults@2
        displayName: "Playwright-Publish Results"
        inputs:
          testResultsFormat: 'JUnit'
          testResultsFiles: '*.xml'
          searchFolder: "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/test-results"
          testRunTitle: "Playwright Tests"  
        condition: always()
```

The pipeline succeeds and the test run display fine:

[image]

The `results.xml` is correctly published to artifact.

[image]

Comment: Yes the 'Tests' tab is populated and I can see a list of the tests that passed/failed for the entire test run. I was hoping to be able to retrieve the raw result.xml file though. That would allow me to pull out some more in-depth stats that I can't work out from the information that is shown on the tests tab.

Comment: If you would like to retrieve the raw result.xml file, firstly check the artifact content `Playwright Test Traces`. If it's not contained, due to the `condition: or(failed(), canceled())`, suppose it has failure or cancelation in your previous step, you need to double check the log of playwright tests step, check the file list to confirm the result.xml is generated indeed.

Comment: Hi @pledgeX, i tested with Playwright test sample project, and defined `reporter: [['junit', { outputFile: 'test-results/results.xml' }]]`  in `playwright.config.js`. The test run display fine , and results.xml can be correctly published to artifact. Please check the update for details, thanks.

Comment: Thanks again Wade Zhou. I can see the results.xml in the test tab now. I think you were right in that the run(s) I was looking at must have failed.

Comment: Glad to know it helps! Happy coding!